# Check with PHP whether a query will execute properly without any error

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to check with PHP whether a query will execute properly without any error.

Say I want to check if inserting a particular record into a table is valid without actually inserting it.

I use the deadly combo PHP + MySQL :)

Comment: You cannot ask PHP something that only MySQL can tell you.

Comment: Im just asking what I feel should be :) Sometimes its not what people wanna answer :D BTW yes I will take care of that

Answer (score 6):

Open new transaction and roll it back after test query execution. Use mysql_error() to check if test query was successful.

Comment: In case of MyISAM I see only one way: use of test (may be temporary) table instead of real one. But that way requires additional SQL-query preprocessing.

Answer (score 3):

1: Open up a mysqli connection `$conn`
`$conn->autocommit(false);`
`$conn->query("INSERT x into y");`
`echo $conn->error;`
`$conn->rollback();`
`$conn->close();  //Without committing changes`

Comment: (+1 for a detailed example of how to implement Valera Leontyev's idea)

Comment: Meh, I started writing this before he posted his - I just took longer since I was putting a code sample together.

Answer (score 1):

start your set of queries with the MySql statement "start transaction", then wrap you following statements in try/catch blocks and then either send a "commit" or a "rollback"

see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) on transactions in mysql